# How Adventureworks DW 2016 is developed using SSIS?

Tags: ssis, etl, adventureworks

I know it's not a new question but maybe somebody find some documentation and/or the sql scripts and SSIS ETL used to create Adventure works DW (2014 at least).
Not sure why Microsoft released a lot about *AdventureWorks for Analysis Services*  ( https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks-analysis-services ) but nothing for SSIS. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adventure works DW (tables and procedures) are part of an executable which installs the SQL objects (facts and dimension) tables in the target edition of SQL Server instance.

Never has been the case to create such dimensional model using SSIS since this data is static and one-off. You may want to create SSIS artifacts on top of this DW and there are a lot of samples and workflows available online for reference.

One such repository on Git is - [Repo link](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/wide-world-importers/wwi-ssis)